# how to show custom attribute message/badge in swagger

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, data-annotations

I have a .NET Web API, and I am using the Redoc library for Swagger display. When I use built-in Data Annotation attributes like 'Required', it shows a little red message in Redoc saying 'Required'. Similarly, when I set a default value for a parameter, it shows that the default value is '{my value}'.

How can I show a similar message or badge in a custom attribute if possible?
Here is an example of what I mean.
[image]

[image]